# How do you name these semirings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, semiring

I came across a family of semirings with no invertible elements. Do these semirings have a special name?

Thanks!

Comment: These are just semirings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a specific terminology for this family of semirings. However, *idempotent* semirings (semirings in which every element satisfies $x^2 = x$) form an important subfamily.

Indeed, suppose that an idempotent element $x$ has an inverse $y$. Then $1 = xy = x^2y = x(xy) = x$. Thus $1$ is the unique invertible element.